# How to find object's dynamic type which overrides the given virtual function?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
struct Base {
  virtual void foo() {}
};

struct Derive1 : Base {
  // missing from the set
  void foo() override { Base::foo(); }
};

struct Derive2 : Derive1 {};

struct Derive3 : Derive2 {
  void foo() override {}
};

void Caller(Base &o) {
    // want to get Derive1
    // typeid(o) will give Derive2
    o.foo();
}

int main() {
    Derive2 x;
    Caller(x);
}
```

I'm trying to resolve the dependency among a set of functions.

I need to keep a set of function definitions which can be called for a given virtual function call. During the execution, if a virtual function is called but missing from the set, I want to be warned about it.

I try to write a unique key into a singleton before `o.foo()` and check if the key is fulfilled in `Base::foo`. But `Derive1::foo` calls `Base::foo`, so the key will be fulfilled and `Derive1::foo` goes unchecked. If I can generate a key linked uniquely to `Derive1` (a.k.a the dynamic type of `o` which overrides `foo`), `Base::foo` won't be able to fulfill the key using its own unique key, and I can get a warning that a virtual function is missing.

In another word, I need two maps `KeyObject` and `KeyType`, where `KeyObject(o, Base::foo) == KeyType(Derive1)`. Equivalent of `KeyObject(o, Base::foo)` will be called in `Caller` and `KeyType(Derive1)` will be called in `Derive1::foo`. This is pseudocode.

Any other solution is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Please learn about *upcasting* and *downcasting*. You need to *downcast* `o` to a reference to a `Derive1` object. You can use either `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `Derive1` is not necessarily defined at call site.

Comment: Then there's really nothing to do. If you need to specifically use the `Derive1` part of the object, you must be able to tell the compiler that.

Comment: You want to find out at what inheritance level the override actually happens? That sounds like reflection, which C++ doesn't have.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The run-time environment knows as `typeid(o)` gives its dynamic type `Derive2`. A run-time warning is good enough.

Comment: @BoP Yes, exactly! Is there any RTTI trick which can do the job? I also accept implementation specific solution.

Comment: @felix - No, there is no language support for this (yet?). As a workaround, I would put the all important `foo` first in each class, and then during codereview ask "Why is there no `foo` in `Derived2`? It should be the very first member!"

Comment: Generally speaking, in a C++ program the need to use things like `typeid` to do decision in code often happens because flaws in the design. And that design flaw could be because of vague or misunderstood requirements or misunderstanding about the problem that should be solved.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Why is that? I know it calls `Derive1::foo`, and it is `Derive1` that I want to find at the call site.

Comment: If you want a reference or pointer to the `Derive1` object part, your only solution is `dynamic_cast` really.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am working on a code base which uses OO. It is old (50 years) , massive (more than 1m lines of code) and no code discipline is ever followed. I'm given a function as the entry, and I need track lots of functions get called down the call graph and respond to any future added overriders or missing overriders rapidly.

Comment: If it's 50 years old, then it has been rewritten several times. 50 years ago C wasn't common outside a few universities, and C++ wasn't invented. The parts you're working with can't be that old, and if requirements changes (which they tend to do for any project running for such long time) then the code needs to change with it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for pointing out, to be frank, I don't know how old it is. It is financial company founded in 1985, so lets say, the code base is 35 years old. Sorry that I go vaguely with this number.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't need a reference nor a pointer to Derive1. In another word, I need two maps `KeyObject` and `KeyType`, where `KeyObject(o, Base::foo) == KeyType(Derive1)`. Equivalent of `KeyObject(o, Base::foo)` will be called in `Caller` and `KeyType(Derive1)` will be called in `Derive1::foo`. **This is pseudocode**.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude A good amount of code remains unchanged since 2008 (when they decide to use git). I doubt if they have the habit in rewriting code before 2008.

Comment: I think you need some static analyzing tool for your code, but since I don't have much expierence with these I cant reccomend something concrete...

Comment: That comment about "`KeyObject` and `KeyType`" is a very good addition to your question. The more details we get about the actual problem you need to solve, the bigger chance of getting answers, and getting better answers.

Comment: @BoP Maybe universal C++ ABI can help, but it seems that we are not there yet. I'm not influential enough to establish any guide lines yet... Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @sklott Static code analyzing is not good enough. The code is massive, I want to start with only a small fraction of the code but it spreads the code base. Global function pointers are used to solve some dependency issue. I will consider this as the last resort.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks. It is added to the question. I no longer hope in having an answer. I'm doing some research in ABI and vtable. Fundamentally, I'm trying to rewrite the OOP code with FP incrementally. During the process, I need to have the code under control.